# Changing href with jQuery. $(id).attr("href", "url") doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the tweet button share the quote from my quote machine. For this I tried changing it's `href` with;-

```
$("#twitter-widget-0").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?ext=" + thisQuote);
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. What can be the problem.

P.S. `"#twitter-widget-0"` is not defined in my html, but this is the ID of the rendered iframe that the twitter button creates.

Here is my pen: http://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/zZGNWw?editors=0110

HTML:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#gen").on("click", function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(json) {

  var author = "";
  var quote = "";

  json.forEach(function(val){
    author+= val.title;    
   quote+= val.content;
  })


  $("#author").html(author);
  $("#mainquote").html(quote);
  var thisQuote = quote + " " + author;
  $("#twitter-widget-0").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?ext=" + thisQuote);
});
  });    


  });
```

Comment: Regarding your postscript that `#twitter-widget-0` is not defined in your html, at what point is that element created? You can't use `$("#twitter-widget-0").attr()` to update an element that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but changing "#twitter-widget-0" to ".twitter-share-button" or even "a" still doesn't help

Comment: Yes, I need to change the href of the `a` tag. The link I have is "twitter.com/share" I need to change it to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?ext=" + thisQuote;

Answer (score 0):

If wasn't working because  `$("#twitter-widget-0").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?ext=" + thisQuote);` was placed within Generate Quote button's on("click") function. So it worked only when the Generate Quote button was clicked first.

If I place the code under `$(document).ready` it works. But without my `thisQuote` var, because it's not a global variable.